# Jquery navi menu toggle

Tags: jquery

I have a toggle navi menu set up for my site, and currently the code allows the user to close the menu when you click the menu link, but it does not close when you click anywhere else on the page. I would like for the menus to hide when the user clicks anywhere EXCEPT inside the active menu. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#toggleLink').click(function() {
    $('#showme1').slideToggle(600);
    $('#showme2,#showme3,#showme4').hide (400);
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#toggleLink2').click(function() {
    $('#showme2').slideToggle(600);
    $('#showme1,#showme3,#showme4').hide (400);

    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#toggleLink3').click(function() {
    $('#showme3').slideToggle(600);
    $('#showme1,#showme2,#showme4').hide (400);

    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#toggleLink4').click(function() {
    $('#showme4').slideToggle(600);
    $('#showme1,#showme2,#showme3').hide (400);
    });
});
</script>`
```

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle?

Comment: I've never used jsFiddle, but I copied and pasted (what I think is) the pertinent code here... http://jsfiddle.net/YgDra/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'd do. Create a div that's hidden initially, and then whenever you toggle one of your menus, show the div (positioned absolutely) behind the menu. Then bind the click even to that div so that whenever it's clicked on it hides the menu.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YgDra/1/)** (if you uncomment the background color in the cover div you'll see how it works)

**Added HTML**

```
<div id="cover"></div>
```

**Added CSS**

```
#cover {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:1;
    display:none;
}
```

**Added jQuery**

```
$('#toggleLink,#toggleLink2,#toggleLink3,#toggleLink4,#toggleLink5').on("click", function () {
    $('#cover').show();
});
$('#cover').click(function () {
    $('#showme1,#showme2,#showme3,#showme4,#showme5').hide(400);
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: This is great! Only problem is, it works in jsFiddle, but not in dreamweaver with the rest of my page code. I've added/edited what you gave me, however now the menus won't show when clicked. So let's say I click on "research tools", nothing pops up. I'm not really sure what the difference is between the jsFiddle and the combined version -- I don't see anything jumping out at me. Any suggestions on what to look for?

Comment: I'd start by opening the browser's developer tools and looking for errors. Usually F12 opens it up.

Comment: Alright it looks like I was missing  }); at the end of the code. Put that in there and now the menus pop back up, but the initial issue (click anywhere outside the div to close the menu) has not been resolved. I still have to click the Menu link (ie Research Tools or Instruction Resources) in order to close the menu.

Comment: Try adding a background color to the cover div like I mention in my answer so you can see if it's showing up properly.

Comment: Ahhhh I finally got it. Thank you so much for your help. It looks like I just needed to set the width and height for cover to be "inherit"... otherwise it wasn't covering the rest of the page content (meaning you could only click on the left side of the page to make the menu disappear, instead of anywhere). But once I set those to inherit it looks like it fixed it. Again, thank you so much for your help! I've been frustrated with this for weeks.

Comment: No problem. If you think my answer helped you please consider upvoting it and/or marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Set it as the accepted answer -- would upvote but I don't have enough rep!